# While loop generating random numbers - part of Monte Carlo Integration

Tags: vb.net, loops, montecarlo

I am trying to create a program that is part of Monte Carlo's Integration.

What I have managed to do is create a loop that generates x and y values a specific number of times that have been requested by the user.

```
Dim ninput As String
ninput = Val(Console.ReadLine())

Dim xvalue As Decimal
Dim yvalue As Decimal

Dim r As New Random()
Dim index As Integer = 0

Do
 index +=1
 xvalue = r.NextDouble()
 yvalue = r.NextDouble()
Loop Until index = ninput
```

The problem I am having is that I need to generate 'pairs' of x and y values between 0 - 1. So if the user input 1, then it'd be one pair of x and y. If they input 30, then I'd need to generate 30 pairs of x and y values. In my case, I just repeat the random function n amount of times.

I don't know how to generate these pairs of x and y values depending on what the user has inputted for n.

Any help is greatly appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Set `Option Strict On` before anything else. -- You can use a two-dimensional array of Double values,  `Double(ninput - 1, 1)` (when `ninput` will actually be a Integer value). It's better to declare the Random object as static (`Shared`), as, e.g., `Private Shared rnd As New Random()`. Then loop `For i As Integer = 0 To ninput - 1`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it would be convenient to have those X, Y pairs in the same entity, so you could create a *class* for them with *members* that store the values.

While you're creating a class, you can add *methods* to it to perform operations on the data, for example you might want an easy way to make a new *instance* of the class, or get some string representation of it.

To store a lot of instances of something, you could use an *array*, but a [*List*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) is often more convenient as it does not need its size (capacity) to be declared in advance: you just add a new item to it and the framework takes care of the storage for you.

So you could have something like:

```
Option Strict On

Module Module1

    Public Class PointDec
        Property X As Decimal
        Property Y As Decimal

        Public Sub New(x As Double, y As Double)
            Me.X = Convert.ToDecimal(x)
            Me.Y = Convert.ToDecimal(y)
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return $"({X}, {Y})"
        End Function

    End Class

    Sub Main()
        Dim nInput As Integer
        Console.Write("Enter number of points to generate: ")
        nInput = Integer.Parse(Console.ReadLine())

        Dim rand As New Random()

        Dim points As New List(Of PointDec)

        For i = 1 To nInput
            points.Add(New PointDec(rand.NextDouble, rand.NextDouble))
        Next

        Console.WriteLine("The first point has a y-value of " & points(0).Y)
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(vbCrLf, points))

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Sample output:

```
Enter number of points to generate: 3
The first point has a y-value of 0.243760395908617
(0.390420139483372, 0.243760395908617)
(0.0321734459289226, 0.175302619661811)
(0.336522278066968, 0.0186830754478849)
```

- It is a good idea to set [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) as the default for new projects: it helps a lot because then Visual Studio can point out several programming mistakes for you.
- I used the Decimal type in PointDec as I assumed you actually needed it instead of Double. The Double type is faster for calculations, and the program might be doing a lot of those with a Monte Carlo simulation.
- The `Val()` function should usually be avoided, as it can accept some things that you'd wouldn't at first glance consider to be a number.

Comment: Good answer. I also suggest, `nInput` should be validated to make sure it is not empty and not nothing. Also, it is better to use Integer.tryParse instead or Integer.Parse. Use Try Catch.

Comment: @Nandostyle I felt that there was only so much that should be introduced in just one answer. Let's see if the OP comes back and says that typing "SEVEN" in as the number throws an exception ;)